# visual basic problem in displaying new form

Tags: vb.net

I want to open form 2 inside the panel of form 1 and open form 3 on clicking button on 2nd form

example:

I'm in **form 1** when i click button the **form 2** will appear inside the panel and if i click the button inside **form 2** the form 2 will be close and **form 3** will appear inside the panel of form 1

This is my code to show **form 2** inside the panel of **form 1** and it works but I don't know how to show **form 3** when I will click the button inside the **form 2**.

```
Sub switchPanel(ByVal panel As Form)
    Panel1.Controls.Clear()
    panel.TopLevel = False
    Panel.Controls.Add(panel)
    panel.Show()
End Sub
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    switchPanel(Form2)
End Sub
```

Comment: This is like homework question

Comment: You've got `panel` with upper and lower case `p`, and also `Panel1` - is that right? Can you also add the code you used to load form3?

Comment: i dont have code to load form 3, that i want to know

Comment: that code works to load form 2 inside the panel of form 1 but i don't know what i need to load form3 using button on form 2

Comment: The Form2 class should declare its own Event, raised by the button click. Be sure to google "controls.clear considered harmful" to find out more about the risk of coding it this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is easy. See my code:

Form1.vb

```
Imports WindowsApp2

Public Class Form1
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    switchPanel(Form2)
End Sub

Public Sub switchPanel(panel As Form)
    Panel1.Controls.Clear()
    panel.TopLevel = False
    Panel1.Controls.Add(panel)
    panel.Show()
End Sub
End Class
```

Form2.vb

```
Imports WindowsApp2

Public Class Form2
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Form2.switchPanel(Form3)
End Sub

Private Shared Sub switchPanel(panel As Form3)
    Form2.Panel1.Controls.Clear()
    panel.TopLevel = False
    Form2.Hide()
    Form1.Panel1.Controls.Add(panel)
    panel.Show()
End Sub
End Class
```